# Understanding and fixing instance handling between classes

Tags: android, android-activity, arraylist, android-context

Im having issues with the app crashing with nullpoint exception.
I know that it crashes when trying to get an ArrayList from pictureTalkFragment. which in this class is only set to PictureTalkFragment ptf;
In other words im trying to get an element (have both getter/setter for the arraylist in ptf, and made the arraylist public as an alternative) from an class and not the instance of that class.

But im just to noob to figure out how to correctly handle getting the instances between classes (activity ---> fragments and back etc). In Java i usually just had an referance in the Constructor that sent the instance/referance with the creation of the new class. But in Android theres all this onCreate (getActivity,getContext ++), Im confused:P When to user where and how:(

the EditPicture was started from this code in GridViewAdapter that extended from PictureTalkFragment (edit in onlongclicklistener)

```
row.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener()

    {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            PopupMenu popMenu = new PopupMenu(v.getContext(), v);
            popMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.picturetalk_popup_menu, popMenu.getMenu());
            popMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {

                        case R.id.edit:

                            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), EditPicture.class);
                            intent.putExtra("itemUUID", item.getId());
                            String s = new String("");
                            context.startActivity(intent);
                            break;

                        case R.id.remove:
                            FileInteraction fileInteraction = new FileInteraction();
                            fileInteraction.deleteFilesAndFolder(item.getImagePath());
                            item.setTitle("");
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                            break;

                        default:
                            //

                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
            popMenu.show();
            return true;
        }
    });
    return row;
```

EditPicture class

```
public class EditPicture extends Activity {

private EditText text;
private Button applyBtn;
private ArrayList<PictureItem> piArray;
private PictureItem pi;
private UUID itemID;
private PictureTalkFragment ptf;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    itemID = (UUID) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("itemUUID");
    SetLocalArray(ptf.getArray());  //Nullpoint here, and i know why. But not how to get the allready created instance of this class
    getPictureItem();
    setContentView(R.layout.picturetalk_edit_pic);
    text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editName);
    text.setText(pi.getTitle());
    applyBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.applyChangeBtn);
    applyBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            updatePictureItem();
            ptf.setArray(piArray);
        }
    });


}

private void updatePictureItem() {

    pi.setTitle(text.toString());
    piArray.add(pi);
    ptf.setArray(piArray);

}

private void SetLocalArray(ArrayList<PictureItem> array) {
    this.piArray = array;
}

private PictureItem getPictureItem() {
    pi = new PictureItem("", "");

    for (int i = 0; i < piArray.size(); i++) {
        if (itemID.equals(piArray.get(i))) {
            pi = piArray.get(i);
            piArray.remove(i);

        }

    }
    return pi;
}}
```

Comment: I cant quite understand what the problem is, your best bet is posting the stacktrace and the line it identifies the problem at.

Comment: I dont get any crash error except Picture talk has stopped working. No output on debugger/logcat etc. When i breakpoint myself through the code it crashes on SetLocalArray(ptf.getArray()); in EditPicture class. My guess is that im trying to get something from an class instead of the instance of this class. And im to noob to figure out how i should get the instance of PictureTalkFragment.

Comment: You haven't instantiated the fragment, put 'ptf = new PictureTalkFragment();' on the line before the SetLocalArra, i dont think your using fragments correctly, but you should get a different error now.

Comment: That is my point, the fragment is instanciated earlier, after all EditPicture were launched from the fragment instance. Setting ptf = new PictureTalkFragment will just return empty an empty fragment and not the inital instance of the fragment. Im having problem on how to get the ptf to be the referance to the instance of PictureTalkFragment, and not a new/uninstanced PictureTalkFragment

Comment: But it's NOT instantiated, as far as i can see anyway... you create the variable 'private PictureTalkFragment ptf;' then in the on create, try and access it, not instantiating anywhere.

Comment: im sorry, i see the confusion. lets put it this way. MainActivity-->Mainfragment(mainmenu), option starts PictureTalkActivity--->PictureTalkFragment(with separate customAdapter for gridview)---->when longpressing picture ---> Popupmenu (select edit) ----> runs EditPicture. Editpicture shall be used to change values in the ArrayList of objects used in PictureTalkFragment to display in the gridview. So i need to from EditPicture Backtrack to the PictureTalkFragment instance, get the arraylist, and edit an object in that arraylist.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are using the array for.
Usually you should not depend on the fragment to get the info, if you want to pass an array of objects to the activity, you should use the Bundle in the activity extras to do so, instead of passing only the UUID, just pass also the array you need.

If you want the lazy option just make a class with a static variable to store the fragment and use it in the activity, which I don't advise.

Comment: Yeah i have understood that fragments are for just the display bit, but took me 20+ classes before i realized it, and ive just tried to figure it all out little by little with dirty patching here and there :P The UUID is just so i know which object in gridview got pressed so i can manipulate it in the next activity (EditPicture). This is my first app and ive gotta deliver it tomorrow morning hopefully working as an school project (to late to start fresh and correct). Will certainly be more clean and correct in future:)